# Tratar caracteres inválidos dentro de um switch

Tags: java

olá, tenho um código que cadastra pessoas e realiza algumas funções de acordo com a opção selecionada no menu que abre no início do programa, as opções vão de 1 a 7, o problema é que se eu ponho qualquer outro caractere fora esses do menu o programa quebra, como consigo tratar esse erro?
Ele esta um pouco desorganizado ainda, ele possui outras classes mas são só métodos de get e set para gravar as informações dentro das listas.

```
package pacotinho;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class NewClass {

public static void menu() {
    System.out.println("\n Escolha uma das seguintes opções:\n\n"
            + " 1 - Inserir dados\n"
            + " 2 - Consultar dados cadastrados\n"
            + " 3 - Sair\n"
            + " 4 - nome Crescente\n"
            + " 5 - nome Crescente, idade Crescente\n"
            + " 6 - nome Decrescente, idade Decrescente, profissao Crescente\n"
            + " 7 - Verificar se existe algo dentro das listas");

    System.out.print(" Opção escolhida: ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> teste = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    List<String> teste1 = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    List<String> teste2 = new ArrayList<String>(3);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("000");
    Relatorio relatorio = new Relatorio();
    Relatorio1 relatorio1 = new Relatorio1();
    Relatorio2 relatorio2 = new Relatorio2();

    int opcao;

    while (true) {
        menu();

        opcao = scan.nextInt();

        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                scan.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    System.out.print("\n\t\t\t\t\t Nome: ");
                    relatorio.setNome(scan.nextLine());
                    relatorio.listagem(opcao);
                    System.out.print("\n\t\t\t\t\t Idade: ");
                    relatorio1.setIdade(scan.nextLine());
                    relatorio1.listagem(opcao);
                    System.out.print("\n\t\t\t\t\t Profissão: ");
                    relatorio2.setProfi(scan.nextLine());
                    relatorio2.listagem(opcao);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                teste.addAll(relatorio.listagem(opcao));
                teste1.addAll(relatorio1.listagem(opcao));
                teste2.addAll(relatorio2.listagem(opcao));
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t                  DADOS");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                for (int i = 0; i < teste.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t " + df.format((i + 1)) + " " + teste.get(i) + " " + teste1.get(i) + " " + teste2.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 4:
                teste.addAll(relatorio.listagem(opcao));
                teste1.addAll(relatorio1.listagem(opcao));
                teste2.addAll(relatorio2.listagem(opcao));
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t                  NOME CRESCENTE");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                Collections.sort(teste);                
                for (int i = 0; i < teste.size(); i++) {                       
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + " " + teste.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 5:
                teste.addAll(relatorio.listagem(opcao));
                teste1.addAll(relatorio1.listagem(opcao));
                teste2.addAll(relatorio2.listagem(opcao));
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t                  NOME CRESCENTE, IDADE DECRESCENTE");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                Collections.sort(teste);
                Collections.sort(teste1, Collections.reverseOrder());
                for (int i = 0; i < teste.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + " " + teste.get(i) + " " + teste1.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 6:
                teste.addAll(relatorio.listagem(opcao));
                teste1.addAll(relatorio1.listagem(opcao));
                teste2.addAll(relatorio2.listagem(opcao));
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t                  NOME DECRESCENTE, IDADE DECRESCENTE E PROFISSAO CRESCENTE ");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________");
                Collections.sort(teste, Collections.reverseOrder());
                Collections.sort(teste1, Collections.reverseOrder());
                Collections.sort(teste2);
                for (int i = 0; i < teste.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t" + " " + teste.get(i) + " " + teste1.get(i) + " " + teste2.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t _____________________________________________\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 7:
                teste.addAll(relatorio.listagem(opcao));
                teste1.addAll(relatorio1.listagem(opcao));
                teste2.addAll(relatorio2.listagem(opcao));
                if (teste.isEmpty() && teste1.isEmpty() && teste2.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("VAZIO");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CONTEM INFORMAÇÕES NA LISTA!");
                }
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t Opção inexistente! Tente novamente.\n\n");
        }

    }

}
```

}

O erro é esse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at pacotinho.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:40)
/home/arthur/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java 
returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 6 segundos)
```

Comment: Seu erro possivelmente está relacionado a esta linha: `opcao = scan.nextInt();`, mas você pode editar sua pergunta e adicionar o erro que você recebe? É a informação mais importante.

Comment: pronto, erro adicionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode obrigar o usuário a inserir um numero valido de 1 a 7 trocando o seu :

```
opcao = scan.nextInt();
```

Para esse algoritmo :

```
int opcao = 0;
while (opcao == 0){
     try{
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         opcao = scan.nextInt();
         //limita os numeros de 1 a 7
         if(!(opcao > 0 && opcao < 8)){
             throw new InputMismatchException();
         }
     } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
         System.out.println("insira um numero inteiro de 1 a 7");
     }
}
```

Quando der um erro de InputMismatchException, ele entra no catch, quando o numero nao for entre 1 a 7, ele tambem força a entrar no catch.
Espero que funcione.

Comment: O que seria essa variavel valorScan? por mais q eu use esse algoritmo, ele impede de iniciar o switch, mas obrigado continuo a testar alguma forma de tratar este erro.

Comment: Me desculpa, a variavel valorScan na verdade era a variavel opcao, eu so tinha esquecido de editar.

Comment: valeu pela ajuda man.